# dynamic breadcrumb from parent to child in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to build a breadcrumb feature that is dynamic. While it works great, it gets rendered with the first element so child component receives the first link at first then the rest follows.

What I want is in the child component to show the correct length of the links passed to it from the parent component. Currently, it shows all links (can loop them well) but the length is equal only to the very first link(s) set on the oninit of parent component.

**Child component :**

```
export class BCComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() breadcrumb:string[];

    last_link_index:number=0; //what is the array index of the last element?    
    constructor() {}

    isActive(row){
     let reply:string='';
     //is it the last link in the breadcrumb?
     if(row==this.breadcrumb.length-1){
        reply='active';
     }
     return reply
    }

    ngOnInit() {

   this.last_link_index=this.breadcrumb.length;

   console.log(this.last_link_index,this.breadcrumb.length,this.breadcrumb);
    }
}
```

In the template, the output is supposed not to create link for the very last element in the array of links.

```
<li *ngFor="let link of breadcrumb;let x=index;" class="breadcrumb-item {{isActive(x)}}">
<i class="fa {{link.icon}}"></i> <a routerLink="/{{link.link}}" href="javascript:void(0)"> {{link.name}}</a>
</li>
```

**Parent Component :**

in parent component, the links will depend on the situation and depth. For example, I have this links:

```
links=[{link:'member/homes',icon:'fa fa-home',text:'Homes Owned'},{link:'#',icon:'fa fa-home-o',text:'RSD8987'}]
```

If it is fixed like this, the links and their length are correct thus renders well. But not if I have further modify the links inside a backend call as shown below :

**Parent component :**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.breadcrumb.push(
        {
        'name':"Plots",
        'link':'members/plots/',
        'icon':'fa-home'
        }
        );

    //get the plot we wanna work with here first
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.requested_home = params['home_id'];

    //Get home description first. build links only if it is found
    this.individual_service.homeDetail(this.requested_home,'n').subscribe(
          data => {

            //home found. So build the links
      this.breadcrumb.push(
        {
        'name':"Text",
        'link':'members/homes/',
        'icon':'fa-tree'
        },

        {
        'name':"Home Detail",
        'link':'#',
        'icon':'fa-sticky-note'
        }
        );
```

The issue now is the child components reports ALL links but the length is just 1 (which is set at the start of init).

Answer (score 0):

Implement ngOnChanges

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes.breadcrumb) {
     this.last_link_index=this.breadcrumb.length;
  }
}
```